# Diversos Update's a partir de um select RAND

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-select

```
UPDATE `tabela` SET `Relacionar_A` =
(SELECT `Relacionar_A` FROM `tabela` WHERE `Relacionar_A`='' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
```

Eu consigo fazer o `update` **único**, apenas 1 registro a partir do `select`.

O que eu gostaria - e que não dei uma procurada (provavelmente não tenha usado as melhores palavras chaves por isto estou aqui) - é saber como eu posso fazer um `update` múltiplo, de diversos registros a partir deste meu `select`.

A ideia é sortear contatos e escolher o número de contatos a serem sorteados e a pessoa a quem este contato será relacionado.

Para sortear utilizo:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `Relacionado_A`='' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $tQuantidade
```

E fazer o `update` de todos esses **registros randômicos de uma vez com a Pessoa Relacionada** a estes registros.

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo dos dados antes e depois da query? Iria ajudar a entender o que quer

Comment: o usuário irá setar a quantidade de registros ($tQuantidade) a serem sorteados e o colaborador a quem estes registros será relacionado ($tRelacionado_A)... eu quero pegar registros randomicos do banco para relacionar ao colaborador e fazer o update de diversos registros de uma vez só... no momento o que consegui mais proximo de qualquer coisa foi isto `UPDATE tabela SET Relacionar_A="$tRelacionado_A" WHERE Relacionar_A = (SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE Relacionar_A='' " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $tQuantidade)`, mas eu só consigo faze isto para um registro, não de forma diversos...